# Como eu aumento uma propiedade CSS usando Js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Eu estou precisando que cada vez que eu aperte em um botão, uma propiedade CSS aumenta em 10, exemplo:

```
<style>div { left: 0; }</style>
<button>Aumentar left em 10</button>
<div></div>
```

E toda vez que eu clicar, ele aumenta o left da Div em 10.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma variável para manter a informação de quantos pixels o elemento deve estar afastado (pela propriedade `left`) e, a cada clique no botão, alterar essa propriedade e computar o novo `left` utilizando a propriedade [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style).

Algo assim:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('#target');

let currentLeft = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentLeft += 10;
  
  // Após adicionar 10 à nossa variável, adicionamos no estilo do elemento:
  div.style.left = `${currentLeft}px`;
});
```

```css
#target {
  left: 0;
  
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<button>Clique!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `offsetLeft` para pegar o valor de `left` se ainda não foi definido.

`offsetLeft` retorna o valor computado de `left`, por exemplo:

O elemento x esta na posição `left` `200px`. `offsetLeft` retornara `200`.

O problema é que `offsetLeft` apenas retorna valores, ele não pode ser definido. Para fazer um elemento se mover teremos que mexer no seu estilo, exemplo: `elemento.style.left`

(Lembrando que para mover um elemento usando `left`, `top`, `right` ou `bottom` é necessário que este elemento tenha a propriedade CSS `position`, tem vários valores possíveis, mas vou demonstrar com o valor `relative`. Link para saber mais sobre os diferentes valores de `position`: [A propriedade position](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position))

```js
function mover(elemento) {
  elemento.style.left = elemento.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
}

/*
Ou no estilo de função em uma variavel:

mover = function(elemento) {
  elemento.style.left = elemento.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
}


Ou uma função de seta:

var mover = (elemento) => {
  elemento.style.left = elemento.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
}
*/
```

```css
body {
  /* PARA ENFEITAR > plano de fundo ciano */
  background: cyan;   
}
button {
  position: relative;
  
  /* PARA ENFEITAR > transição de 1 segundos */
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!-- O "this" de "mover(this)" se refere ao elemento do proprio botão -->
<button onclick="mover(this)">Clica aqui para me mover!</button>
```